# Unable to create Storage account on Azure C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage-account

I am trying to create a storage from c# in asp.net MVC application but it throws me error Account type StandardLRS is invalid as you can see below

[image: Exception]

Below is the code which I am using for creation

```
string token = GetAccessToken("sub id", "app name", "tenant id");
                var Credentials = new TokenCredentials(token);

                var resourceManagementClient = new ResourceManagementClient(Credentials);
                resourceManagementClient.SubscriptionId = "sub id";

                var storageProvider = resourceManagementClient.Providers.Register("Microsoft.Storage");

                var storageManagementClient = new StorageManagementClient(Credentials);
                storageManagementClient.SubscriptionId = "sub id";

                string rgName = "TimedCloudRG" + location.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty);

                var resourceGroup = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resources.Models.ResourceGroup
                {
                    Location = location
                };
                var rgResult = resourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.CreateOrUpdate(rgName, resourceGroup);

                Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Sku DefaultSku = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Sku(Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.SkuName.StandardLRS);
                Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Kind DefaultKind = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Kind.Storage;                       
                Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.StorageAccountCreateParameters parameters = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.StorageAccountCreateParameters()
                {
                    Kind = DefaultKind,
                    Sku = DefaultSku,                    
                    Location = rgResult.Location
                };


                string stAccName = "TCStorageAccount"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);

                var storageAccount = await storageManagementClient.StorageAccounts.CreateAsync(rgName, stAccName, parameters);
```

Surprisingly it works fine when I run it on console application. I also try to install Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent package but unable to install as my project .net framework selected as 4.5.1 and this package not supported to that version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I leveraged [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage 6.2.0-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage) which supports `.NETFramework 4.5` to check this issue. I specified the `Location` as `West US` and I could create my storage account.

> string stAccName = "TCStorageAccount"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);

AFAIK, your account name is not a valid storage account name. Storage account name must be **between 3 and 24 characters** in length and **use numbers and lower-case letters** only.

I tried to create storage account on Azure Portal and accidentally found the following result:

[image]

As [Locally redundant storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#locally-redundant-storage) mentioned as follows:

> Some applications are restricted to replicating data only within a country due to data governance requirements. A paired region could be in another country. For more information on region pairs, see [Azure regions](https://azure.microsoft.com/regions/).

Additionally, you could use [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent 1.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent/1.0.0) which supports `.NETFramework 4.5`.

**UPDATE:**

I created a sample [AspDotNet-MVC-CreateAzureStorageAccount](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-MVC-CreateAzureStorageAccount) and defined the `CreateAzureStorageAccount` action for creating storage account under [HomeController.cs](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-MVC-CreateAzureStorageAccount/blob/master/CreateAzureStorageAccount/WebApplication1/Controllers/HomeController.cs). Here is the test result, you could refer to it as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I have upgrade the DLL Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage from version 5.2.0-preview to 6.5.0-preview and also i have upgrade my code and as per your suggestion i have make the storage account name in lowercase now  but i have still the same exception. I have tried with the same location but it still giving me same error that Account type is invalid. Even though I tried with all account types like standardGRS etc but still the same exception.

Comment: What is your location for creating storage account? Have you tried to create the storage account on Azure Portal to narrow this issue?

Comment: I am able to create the storage account on west US, australia east on portal with standardLRS on the portal without having any issues but not with c# code.

Comment: I updated my answer with the code sample for creating azure storage account, you could refer to it.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? What is the cause for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem calling the REST API's directly. I was missing the underscore between Standard and LRS. The AccountType needs to be specified exactly as seen in the ARM templates, in this case Standard_LRS or Standard_GRS.