# Unable to create Storage account on Azure ARM using Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, web

I am trying to create a storage account using Web API but it is giving me the exception that method not allowed as shown below

[image: Web Api Exception]

Below is my code:

```
    string stAccName = "TCStorageAccount" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
    stAccName = stAccName.ToLower();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            var payloadText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);

writer.Write(payloadText);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            using (var content = new StreamContent(stream))
            {
                content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                content.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2016-12-01");
                Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{2}?api-version=2016-12-01", "subid", "resource group name", stAccName));

var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
           }
       }
   }
```

I also tried with another way as discussed in this thread [Unable to create Storage account on Azure C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984311/unable-to-create-storage-account-on-azure-c-sharp) but still unable to create a storage account.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why not use the [NET Client API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Because i am facing issues in use .net client as explained in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984311/unable-to-create-storage-account-on-azure-c-sharp

Comment: Create storage account is a `PUT` operation and not a `POST` operation. Please change your method from `PostAsync` to `PutAsync` and that should solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because [`Create Storage Account`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/create) is a `PUT` request and not a `POST` request.

Please change  the following line of code:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

to

```
var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);
```

and you should not get this `Method Not Allowed (405)` error.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply. The error is remove but getting new exception now 

`{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1'
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The error is remove but getting new exception now `{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1'

The exception is cause by providing wrong parameters for storage account. You could view the detail error message using following code after the response came back.

```
string detailError = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Here is a sample parameters which could create a storage account successfully using your code on my side.

```
{
  "kind": "Storage",
  "location": "South Central US",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_LRS"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much it helps a lot.